# Limit field length of data returned from elastic search

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am using Javascript Api of elastic search for the back end I have set up . I have a field text that is kind of lengthy . Is it possible to get just a portion of this field ? .

I tried using Search Highlighting of elastic search . But dint work !!

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in snippets of the results near matched query terms, you can use pass a [highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) parameter to limit the length of data returned.

```
GET _search
{
    "query" : {...},
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "<name of your field>" : {
                "fragment_size" : <desired length>,
                "no_match_size" : <desired length>,
                "number_of_fragments" : 1,
                "pre_tags" : [""],
                "post_tags" : [""],

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Setting `pre_tags` and `post_tags` to empty strings prevents ElasticSearch from wrapping matching text with tags.  If the query didn't match anything in `<name_of_your_field>`, then a snippet from the beginning of the field is returned.

Comment: This answer helped me :) ! I was using an attachment processor to index pdf files. With highlights applied to search, I could limit the content returned from the search result in the attachment.content field. Thank you @drs.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two approaches.

1. You can explore the possibility of storing one more field in your docs which represent a shorter version of the required field like first 30 characters. This will return results faster but will need some work on your side.
2. You can use Script fields, it allows you to run a groovy script on any field you are interested in, in your case a simple sub string call: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-script-fields.html